# Angular material dialog not showing data properly

Tags: angular

In my application am handling errors globally, if I got any error am just opening
mat dialog to show error description and code.

Issue is when dialog opened it showing empty after few seconds data is  showing,
I tested by debugging data is sending properly, but it is taking time to show error description and error code
and  is this right approach for handling errors globally?

```
import {ErrorHandler,Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { errorDialog }  from '..error-dialog/error-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogConfig, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler{
  constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog) {
    super();
  }
  handleError(error: any) {
    this.logError(error);
  }
  logError(error: any) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        this.openGenericErrorDialog("BackEndErrorMessage",error.status);
    }
    else{
      throw error;
    }
  }

  openErrDialog(errMsg?: string,errCode?:number): void {
    const dialogData = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogData.autoFocus = false;
    dialogData.data = {
      errorDescription: errMsg,
      errorCode:errCode
    };
    if(dialogData.data){
            this._dialog.open(errorDialog , dialogData);
    }


  }
}
```

I have added `afterContentInit` life cycle hook in `errorDialog` component, after `afterContentInit` method loads am setting `isLoad` flag to true 
in HTML using `ngIf` directive, if `isLoad` true am showing dialog content. This is working as expected but when component loaded small empty dialog is showing.

How to load HTML content `afterContentInit`? how to restrict before loads

ErrorDialogComponent:

```
import { Component, Inject,AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector   : 'error-dialog',
    templateUrl: './error-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./error-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorDialogComponent implements AfterContentInit
{
    errorCode:string;
    isLoaded:boolean=false;
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ErrorDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data)
    {
        this.errorCode=data.errorCode;
        this.errorDescription=data.errorDescription;
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(){
        this.isLoaded=true; 
    }
}


<div  *ngIf="isLoaded" >
    {{errorDescription}}
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the full code of the error dialog component.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim updated